# The requested operation caused a stack overflow

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a derived class and the error pops up. Not quite sure how it comes out. Please help!

Base class:

```
public class Command : identifiableobject
{
    LookCommand l = new LookCommand();

    public virtual string Execute (Player p, string[] text)
    {
        return "";

    public Command (string[] ids) : base(ids)
    {
    }
}
```

Derived class

```
public class LookCommand : Command
{
    public LookCommand () : base (new string[] {"look"})
        {
        }
}
```

The error pops up when I try to create a new Command Object. Any ideas why?

Comment: Look at your stack trace!

Comment: What is "identifiableobject"? Does the error occur if you remove it temporarily?

Comment: Also, your `Execute` method isn't complete. Basically, we can't help you with so little information.

Comment: @asawyer my track trace keeps going back and forth between those 2 @@. Why??? I thought when I use base for LookCommand it's only use the constructor of Command only and nothing else?

Comment: @JonSkeet that's method is done and I'm pretty sure that's not the main problem!

Comment: I dare say it's not - in which case you should either not include it, or include it completely, with the closing brace. Why include it in a broken fashion?

Comment: @JonSkeet oh sr, miss copying!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
public class Command : identifiableobject
{
    LookCommand l = new LookCommand();

    ...
```

That means that in order to construct a `Command`, you need to construct a new `LookCommand`. But a `LookCommand` *is* a `Command`, so constructing one `LookCommand` requires constructing another one, which constructs another one, etc.

We don't know what you're trying to achieve with the `l` variable here, but that's what's causing the Either you need to get rid of that variable, or don't initialize it in that way, or make `LookCommand` not derive from `Command`.

Comment: Thanks I have just figured that out. I totally forget about the inheritance in this case. Thanks so much!